# Bank Deposit Scam

Tags: scams

I was on Instagram and saw someone's post about making extra cash.

I inboxed her for details and she said her manager will deposit funds into my account, then I would send them $2000 to split between the both of them.

She stated that I would need to overnight my bankcard to her so her manager can process the deposit.

She didn't ask for anything (neither SSN nor routing or account number) but the bank card only.

I assume that it is a scam.

Can anyone elaborate on this type of scam?

*She claim it's not a scam.*

Comment: Do you honestly think it's a good idea to send someone your bankcard? A card they could use to make purchases wherever they want and clear out your bank account.

Comment: Lakyn - of course it's a scam.  Criminals use these schemes to "launder" money, you know?  Note that this is **worse than normal scams** because it's the type of scam where not only do you lose money, but ***YOU GET IN TO MAJOR CRIMINAL TROUBLE***.  Note that ***YOU*** can ***END UP IN JAIL*** doing this.  *Even if* you "didn't understand".  It's that simple.

Comment: What are you getting paid to do? If you don't have a clear answer, it's a scam.

Comment: There's no possibility ever that a legitimate business would ever need to make money transfers or payroll out of some third party's personal account.

Answer (score 30):

This is absolutely a scam. The easiest way to tell is to ask why they would involve a total stranger as a 50% partner rather than keep all the money to themselves. What value do you bring to the table?

Answers:

1) They are engaged in criminal activity and using you to launder money. You are the one law enforcement will likely arrest leaving them anonymous. This option is pretty unlikely.

2) The will deposit the money somehow, in a way that will take a while to be detected as fraud (fake cashier's check, etc.). It will be just long enough for you to send them the $2,000 and run off with it before the bank reverses their deposit and leaves you in a hole and possibly trouble with the law for depositing fake checks. Semi-Likely

3) They will use your bank card to buy a bunch of stuff and never call you back or deposit any money. Or possibly they will do a deposit that will bounce. Most likely.

The fact that this is a scam is painfully obvious. Unfortunately these things often work because people's greed overpowers their common sense.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, if someone is offering to give you money for free, it's a scam. Selling an Xbox on Craigslist and someone is offering to pay more than it'd cost to buy a new one? They're going to reverse the payment, or it's a stolen credit card. Someone wants to send you 10% of three point six million dollars in exchange for "helping get it out of the country"? It's a scam. If you can't put your finger on precisely what value you, specifically add to the equation, it's a scam. Or just a really, really bad job.

Answer (score 8):

This particular scam is making the rounds of the freelance job hunter sites right now.  I recently filed complaints with UpWork and FreeLancer about it because they have a number of postings doing this same kind of scheme.

The thing is, it preys on the desperation of some people, and it keeps going because it succeeds in finding willing victims.  It makes me sick to my stomach to see people get taken like that, but the rule of thumb "if it sounds too good to be true, it probably is" seems to be forgotten by so many people out there.

The fact that you're questioning it is all the proof you need that you should avoid this like the plague.  What sense would it make for someone to send you a check to deposit, only to then send some of the cash back to them?  I'm glad you asked before falling for this one.

Good luck!

Comment: It violates both the "too good to be true rule" as you mentioned and the "turn it around the other way" rule.  That one is that if you can't say yes to, "Does it make good business sense to pay someone to do this job?", then it probably isn't good business.